# Tkinter scrolling frame: expand frame to fit content Canvas in one direction

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a frame with a set height and a vertical scroll bar that responds to mouse scroll events. The frame needs to contain frames, so there's no built-in Tk widget I can use. Here's the Python 3 code I'm working with, derived from several related answers on here:

```python
import tkinter as tk

class VertScrollingFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.bar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = "vertical", command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.bar.lift(self.frame)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.bar.set)

        self.bar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = 'both', expand = True)
        self.canvas.create_window(
            (4, 4),
            window = self.frame,
            anchor = "nw", 
            tags = "self.frame",
        )
        #self.frame.pack()

        def on_cfg(_):
            self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', on_cfg)

        def on_scroll(event):
            if event.delta:
                amount = round(-event.delta / 120)
            else:
                amount = {4: -1, 5: 1}[event.num] * 2
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(amount, "units")

        bind_keys = {'<MouseWheel>', '<Button-4>', '<Button-5>'}
        def scroll_bind(_):
            for key in bind_keys:
                self.canvas.bind_all(key, on_scroll)
        def scroll_unbind(_):
            for key in bind_keys:
                self.canvas.unbind_all(key)

        self.frame.bind('<Enter>', scroll_bind)
        self.frame.bind('<Leave>', scroll_unbind)

root = tk.Tk()
win = tk.Toplevel(root)
sf = VertScrollingFrame(win)
for _ in range(20):
    f = tk.Frame(sf.frame)
    for x in range(12):
        tk.Button(f, text = str(x)).pack(side = 'left')
    f.pack()
sf.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I've filled the scrolling frame with a wide grid of buttons, and the canvas appears to be resizing horizontally to fit them, but the `ScrollingFrame` isn't. It just cuts off the right side of the content. How can I make the frame expand to fit its contents horizontally?

With the call to `self.frame.pack()` uncommented, I get a different incorrect result: the grid of buttons is strangely cropped both vertically and horizontally, and there's nothing to scroll.

Comment: @stovfl I don't think so. I want a frame to expand to fit its contents, not its container.

Comment: It's the same, just the oposite: ***"Canvas will not expand to fit Frame"***: Change to: `self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"), width=self.frame.winfo_width())`

Comment: @stovfl Oh, I see. That works. Thanks!